# Python Prompt closes immediately when doing arithmetic operations in a script

Tags: python

I am new to python and in a script of python after asking the user the values of variables the window closes automatically for eg.

```
a=int(input("Enter the first number here"))
b=int(input("Enter the second number here"))
c=a+b
print("The answer is :", c)
```

This takes my input and then without printing the third statement it autocloses after hitting enter at input from b.
I seriously need help as I need to show this in a project.
I'll be very grateful towards you if you answer
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It probably *did* print the answer, but then exited before you could read it.  Try putting something like `input("Press Enter to exit")` at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the prompt first, and then executing the python program. If you are simply double-clicking the file to run it, the prompt will close as soon as execution completes, which is right after your `print` statement. Another option, as someone mentioned in the comments, is to add `input("Press Enter to exit")` below the print statement, but I would strongly suggest going with the first solution I mentioned as it is a far better habit to build.